# PythonOperator task hangs accessing Cloud Storage and is stacked as SCHEDULED

Tags: google-cloud-composer

One of the tasks in my DAG sometimes hangs when accessing Cloud Storage. It seems the code stops at the `download` function here:

`hook = GoogleCloudStorageHook(google_cloud_storage_conn_id='google_cloud_default')
for input_file in hook.list(bucket, prefix=folder):
    hook.download(bucket=bucket, object=input_file)`

In my tests the folder contains a single 20Mb json file.

The task normally takes 20-30 seconds, but in some cases it will run for 5 minutes, and after that its state is updated to `SCHEDULED` and stuck there (waited for more than 6 hours). I suspect the 5 minutes are due to the configuration `scheduler_zombie_task_threshold 300` but not sure.

If I clear the task manually on the Web UI, the task is quickly queued and run again correctly. I am getting around the issue by setting an `execution_timeout` which updates the task correctly to `FAILED` or `UP_FOR_RETRY` state when it takes longer than 10 minutes; but I'd like to fix the underlying issue to avoid relying on a fixed timeout threshold, any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a discussion on the Cloud Composer Discuss group about this: https://groups.google.com/d/msg/cloud-composer-discuss/alnKzMjEj8Q/0lbp3bTlAgAJ. It is a problem with the Celery executor when Airflow workers die.

Although Composer is working on a fix, if you want this to happen less frequently in the current version, you may consider reducing your parallelism Airflow configuration or creating a new environment with a larger machine-type.